# Failing to get MSMQ WCF Window Service to function

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

I'm trying to create a MSMQ WCF service, although I'm having troubles running the code.  It fails when trying to create an instance of the service.  I have MSMQ installed, and can confirm there is a private created called '*servicemodelsamples*'

When running the service, I received the following error;

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error opening the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running,
>   the queue exists and has proper authorization to be read from. The
>   inner exception may contain additional information. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.MsmqException: An error occurred while opening the
>   queue:Unrecognized error -1072824283 (0xc00e0025). The  message cannot
>   be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and
>   running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the
>   required access mode and authorization.

Control Service Interface and Implementation.

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IControlService
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
   void PricingAlert(int eventid, int marketid);
}

public class ControlService : IControlService
{
    public ControlService()
    { }

    public void PricingAlert(int eventid, int marketid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Acknowledged");
    }
}
```

Service1.cs Service starting code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    string queueName = Settings.Default["queueName"].ToString();

    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queueName))
        MessageQueue.Create(queueName, true);

    if (myServiceHost != null)
    {
        myServiceHost.Close();
    }
    myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ControlService));
    myServiceHost.Open();    // *** Code Fails Here
}
```

The application config;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="ControlService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="netMsmqBindingConfig">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TheControlService.ControlService" behaviorConfiguration="MSMQBindingBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="net.msmq://172.26.2.11/private/ServiceModelSamples"
                  binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="netMsmqBindingConfig"
                  contract="TheControlService.IControlService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MSMQBindingBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8000/Hello/" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="controlserviceerrors.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <applicationSettings>
    <ControlService.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="queueName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>.\private$\ServiceModelSamples</value>
      </setting>
    </ControlService.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?  I suspect it might because I've based the code on an example which was a winforms application.

Comment: Last time this happened to me it actually *was* a security problem. In some operating systems, default permissions don't allow you to read from the queue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one? I have a similar problem; running integration tests from Visual Studio works, but running them on the build server (agent is on my computer), I get the same exception message.

Comment: We ran into this and found a workaround by deleting and re-adding the queues.  I suspect that may be a red herring, but you might try it.  Also, [this MSMQ FAQ](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/68300738/MSMQ-faq) mentions that it's probably an Active Directory issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the user under which the Service is running. Add **permission** to the queues manually.
If the queues have broken permissions you should reset the permissions manually in `C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage\lqs` using a notepad.